# How to fix shower hose covering

Tags: shower, hose

In my shower, the hose covering has snapped off somehow.

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

Here's a closer look:
[image]

I don't think the covering is metallic, but it's a chromed plastic-like material (not sure what it's called).

Is it salvageable or should it be replaced?

Comment: Just replace.  You can get a new hose—extra long, even—for less than a yuppie food stamp.  They're pretty much all the same thread.

Answer (score 4):

Whether you should repair or replace is a matter of opinion and off-topic.

*Can* it be repaired? Sure. Some tape or silicone sealant would probably hold that end up. It won't look very good and isn't likely to hold up for very long, but you can repair it that way as often as you'd like.

Alternatively, you could replace it for, likely, not much money. It appears to screw onto both ends - at the wall and at the hand-held shower head, so unscrew it, let it dry out and take it to the store with you (not nice to drip water on the slick store floors). Go to the plumbing parts section to figure out what type of thread and diameter you have, then go to the bathroom accessories aisle and pick out a replacement hose with that size fitting. Odds are good that they're all the same and you could skip the parts aisle, but I'll throw that in, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

It's **probably** just broken and replacement will be the best option.

There's a *small* possibility that the covering actually "screws" into the fitting it's no longer in, and has come "unscrewed" (note I'm talking about the covering, not the regular pipe threads on the inner part) through handling (always twisting one direction when putting it away or something like that.)

That may also not be the case, or there may be broken covering jammed in if it is the case, that's you'd have to remove first. This is just a possibility to look for.

[image]